# How to project value object (component) into a DTO?

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

Is it possible to transform component into a dto when creating projections via SelectList.

I have a value object Name, and I need to project it into a Dto NameInfo. Below is the query.
I need a step here on this line

```
.Select(c=> coveredInsured.Name).WithAlias(()=>info.Name)
```

something along the lines

```
 .Select(c => new NameInfo { Last= c.Last, First=c.First, Middle = c.Middle}).WithAlias(()=>info.Name)
```

This is the actual query that fails becuase it cannot convert Name into NameInfo. So. other then exposing three properties on my dto, is there a way to project?

```
   .SelectList(list => list
                        .Select(c => c.Id).WithAlias(() => info.CoverageId)
                        .Select(c => bid.Year).WithAlias(() => info.PolicyYear)
                        .Select(c => bid.OptionNumber).WithAlias(() => info.OptionNumber)
                        .Select(c=> ((ClientBase)client).Number).WithAlias(()=>info.ClientNumber)
                        .Select(c => c.PrimaryInsured.Id).WithAlias(() => info.PrimaryInsuredId)
                        .Select(c => c.CoveredInsured.Id).WithAlias(() => info.CoveredInsuredId)
                        .Select(c=> coveredInsured.Name).WithAlias(()=>info.Name)
                             )
                .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<InsuredCoverageInfo>())
                .List<InsuredCoverageInfo>()
            .ToList();
```